# map contains value as a list+how to print in C++

Tags: c++

I have a map having strings as keys and lists of file names as values.
ex: `Map(firstDir, list(file1,file2,file3))`

I know that by using following code I can print value which is of String

```
{
    cout << "Key: " << pos->first << endl;
    cout << "Value:" << pos->second << endl;
}
```

But if `pos->second` contains a List, how to display?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

overload `operator <<` for list

```
std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out, std::list<ListElemType> const& lst)
{
   for(std::list<ListElemType>::iterator it = lst.begin(); it != lst.end(); ++it)
   {
       if(it != lst.begin())
          out << /*your delimiter*/;  
       out << *it;
   }
   return out;
}
```

now you can do what you want

```
cout << "Key: " << pos->first << endl << "Value:" << pos->second << endl;
```

Comment: A more elegant way would be to use `std::copy` with an `std::ostream_iterator`. You can specifiy a custom delimiter for that too.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y : your way is more stl-style, but i wouldn't say it is elegant because I don't believe it is very readable.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: the thing is that with copy and ostream iterators the delimiter will be applied after each element, not inbetween them. Hence my choice

Comment: You are right, @Roger Pate already pointed that out on my answer.

Comment: I don't understand, why do people give high scores for answers which make things more complicated than they are. Operator overloading is another concept in C++. Why introducing a new concept in an answer, if it could be explained without. The answer should be imho: "treat pos->second" as an instance of std::list. (s. my version below)"

Answer (score 2):

How about using Boost.Foreach ?

```
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

{
    cout << "Key: " << pos->first << endl;
    cout << "Values:" << endl;
    BOOST_FOREACH(std::string const& file, pos->second)
    {
      cout << "\t" << file << endl;
    } 
}
```

Comment: @rubenvb: Because without 0x, it's quite a bit more cumbersome than BOOST_FOREACH.

Comment: @Roger: ah yes, I'm spoiled that way :) using GCC 4.5 and MSVC 2010 exclusively... I forget what horrors needed to be written before.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you would have to decide is how do you want the list to be displayed? Separated by commas or each entry in a new line perhaps? Then, you could overload the stream output operator for lists of strings:

```
std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & stream, const std::list<std::string> & object) {
    std::copy(object.begin(), object.end(), std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, ", ")
}
```

This operator will get called everytime you write am `std::list<std::string>` to any output stream, and it will print the values of the list separated by commas.

Comment: Though the commas don't *separate,* they terminate each item: `"a, b, "` for a list with two items.

Answer (score 2):

Use a library which overloads stream inserters for containers, such as [my example](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/6f5692c4f9d2/cpp/kniht/streamutil.hpp#cl-108):

```
void example(MapType const &m) {
  using namespace kniht::container_inserters;  // must be enabled in this scope
  MapType::const_iterator x = m.begin();

  cout << *x << '\n';  // can print the pair directly

  cout << "Key: " << x->first << '\n';  // or format it yourself
  cout << "Value: " << x->second << '\n';
  // output for a list: [a, b, c]
}
```

You can extract the used functions from my [header](http://bitbucket.org/kniht/scraps/src/6f5692c4f9d2/cpp/kniht/streamutil.hpp) or simply copy it elsewere (it's self-contained, but does have other utilities).

Comment: @Roger: Any plans to propose your library to boost? :) I mean, from the looks of it, it's at least as boostworthy as boost assign

Comment: @Armen: I wouldn't call it a library (that whole repo is random assorted bits); I actually thought Boost had something for this, but can't find it.

Comment: @Roger: I don't mean the repo, I mean the project in broader sense

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using STL the most simple way to print such structure is the next one:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map<string, list<string>> sample;

   ... //fill the map

    for (auto itr : sample){
        cout << itr.first << ":\t" << endl;
        for (auto innerItr : sample.second)
            cout << innerItr << " ";
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to be able to do though is to create a template that can output any printable sequence, i.e. a sequence of printable items. You also want to be able to customise how you start, end and delimit the sequence.

So create your own wrapper class. Now because it is your wrapper you can overload operator<< happily on it without interfering with an external namespace.

You could use a boost::range in its constructor, or a templated being/end sequence or a templated collection.

Also take as parameters your delimiters. You can have reasonable defaults if you want though,

Finally when you wish to print one, you just do something like:

```
std::cout << MySequenceFormatter( seq.begin(), seq.end(), delim, startofSeq, endOfSeq ) << std::endl;
```

When outputting maps, you can use a boost::transform_iterator in between to transform each std::pair as you iterate through the sequence. Then you can have you own pair formatter too.
In fact you can do this for any sequence where you wish to use a custom method to print the items themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Strait forward version (-:

```
#include <map>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream> // only for generating testdata

typedef std::list<std::string> TStringList;
typedef std::map<std::string, TStringList> TStringListMap;

TStringListMap myMap;

int main()
{
  // Generating testdata
  for (int i=0;i<10;i++)
  {
    std::stringstream kstr;
    kstr << i;
    std::string key = kstr.str();        
    for (int ii=0;ii<=i;ii++)
    {
      std::stringstream vstr;
      vstr << ii;
      myMap[key].push_back( vstr.str() );
    }  
  }

  //Print map
  for ( TStringListMap::const_iterator it = myMap.begin(), end = myMap.end(); it != end; ++it )
  {
    std::cout << it->first<< ": ";
    for( TStringList::const_iterator lit = it->second.begin(), lend = it->second.end(); lit != lend; ++lit )
    {
      std::cout << *lit << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0: 0
1: 0 1
2: 0 1 2
3: 0 1 2 3
4: 0 1 2 3 4
5: 0 1 2 3 4 5
6: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
7: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
8: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
9: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```